# Weird race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I am having an issue with the method I wrote. What is does, is wait for a property to equal another value. I can't reproduce it here, but in the unit test I am running, I want to wait for a particular value to be true. It prints out "wait", and then "notify" (indicating that it should be working correctly), but "done waiting" is never printed. It doesn't always do it, and sometimes it works flawlessly, this is why I think it's some sort of race condition.

I was using the Locking API before, but was getting the same issues so I decided to try the old wait/notify stuff.

Could it possibly be the listener being created and called, before it has a chance to wait? Even if this was the issue, it shouldn't print "wait", and then "notify". Even if I print the ms at the time of "wait" and "notify", wait still comes before notify.

```
private static <T> void waitFor(ObservableValue<T> value, T wantedValue) throws InterruptedException {
    if (value.getValue() != wantedValue) {
        Object lock = new Object();
        synchronized (lock) {
            value.addListener((observableValue, t, t1) -> {
                if (value.getValue() != wantedValue) {
                    return;
                }
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.print("notify");
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            });
            System.out.println("wait");
            lock.wait();
            System.out.println("done waiting");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Among other issues, every call to this makes its own lock.

Comment: Why on earth would you switch from a locking API. What do you think `Object lock = new Object();` is doing? Did you even try debugging?

Comment: isn't the listener that is added using the same lock object?

Comment: @MartinSerrano The listener is accessing the same lock object. This is what I don't understand. When I make the lock a static field, it works. Could cause issues with other uses if for example, many threads were using this util method, only one thread would be allowed to wait for any particular property.

Comment: If it wasn't obvious, I'm not using the lock to lock any value, I'm using it to block the method call return. Hence the `waitFor`. It shouldn't block other threads from using this method, it should only block the calling thread until the value changes to a desirable result.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Object lock = new Object();
    synchronized (lock) { ...
```

does not make sense.

Multiple threads must use the *same* object to synchronize on, or the synchronization is just not happening.

At the end, your code keeps waiting for a signal which no other thread could ever send to the `lock` object, because that object is local to the method.

**Edit:** Please ignore the above. It's just based on my overlooking of that the lock object is passed to the anonymous listener which does get handed out of the method.

However, another potential race condition is in

```
if (value.getValue() != wantedValue) {
    Object lock = new Object();
    synchronized (lock) { ...
```

What if the value changes asynchronously *after* `getValue()` but before `value.addListener(...)` is executed?

And another minor issue: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) for `wait()` states "spurious wakeups are possible, and **this method should always be used in a loop**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: If I make the lock object static, it works. I do not understand this behaviour though. I am blocking the calling thread until the appropriate value is there (then the listener wakes the thread). This is why I had one lock object per method call. If I make it static, then only one call could be performed at one time (this would be an issue for a util method called from different parts of the program). The only threads that are accessing the lock are the calling thread, and the listener thread. Could you explain this behaviour?

Comment: In fact, I wish I could remove my upvote. Although this fixes the problem, I might call it a work around. Your logic is being applied to a standard locking scenario. As I said, I want to block the calling thread, NOT all threads accessing the method. It is intentional to have a single lock per call.

Comment: And with more testing, using a static variable doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The comments about your lock so far are overlooking an important detail. Your lock variable is actually *NOT* a local variable. It is "effectively final" in Java 8 because it's referenced inside your listener closure. This means it's actually being copied into a special compiler-generated field in the anonymous class implementing the closure object and because of this, it is actually potentially shared between the thread that calls waitFor() and whatever thread might call the registered listener closure. So, I think this is not the problem at all.

However, depending on what you're expecting to happen, there is a possible race condition in your code. The listener is being added before you call wait(), which means that if there is an immediate asynchronous notification before you can even get to wait(), the listener's call to notifyAll() will be missed and the code will wait forever for the notification that already happened. Of course, if you're expecting more notifications in the future, this isn't really a problem because you'll unblock when the next notification comes along, but I expect you're seeing this bug in a unit test where you're waiting for only one notification and you're simply missing it sometimes which is causing your test to fail *sometimes*.

One further thought. Maybe you could change your code to:

ObservableValue.waitFor(T value)

Code is almost always better without the static keyword (I wish it didn't exist). And if ObservableValue is an interface, you can always make waitFor() a default method since you're in Java 8.

Comment: I was thinking what you said in the second paragraph, that is why I locked (synchronized) *before* adding the listener. Once it's locked, the notify call should be blocked until I wait. Then the lock should be released and the listener synchronized block will call. I'm confused what you mean about making the waitFor not static. ObservableValue is a JavaFX thing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html

Comment: @JonathanLocke Gee, you're right. The code actually *is* handing out the lock object. However, the race condition you're seeing in fact isn't there: The `lock` is already held when the listener is added and not released until the `wait()`, which is the first chance for the listener to call `notifyAll()` on that lock. So that should work out.

Comment: Actually, `lock` _is_ a local variable.  It is a local variable in the `waitFor`method.  There is another variable, also named `lock`, which is a final field of the anonymous inner class.  The field is initialized to point to the same object to which the local `lock` points when the inner object is instantiated.

Comment: You are both correct Hanno and James. Chris, didn't realize this was a JavaFX class. It does seem like this should work. The only thing left I can think of is that maybe the checking of this observable both outside the synchronized block and inside it in the callback somehow violates the Java Memory Model's issue with "double checked locking". If that's the case, this is Java 8 code so it should be possible to make double-checked locking work, but it does require some thinking. It might also require modifying the value being checked to make it volatile.